# How to get url using Imicors

Tags: web-scraping, macros, imacros

How to get url in tags  by class name in iMicros .

I have below micro, I want to get url in anchor tag of class name `item-name`

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.searspartsdirect.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:partSearchForm ATTR=ID:partSearchText CONTENT=420479P
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:partSearchForm ATTR=ID:searchParts
TAG POS=4 TYPE=DIV ATTR=A:ITEM-NAME* EXTRACT=HREF
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to search for the url that is `part-number/*your search*/what ever/what ever.html` like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.searspartsdirect.com/
SET !VAR1 420479P
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:partSearchForm ATTR=ID:partSearchText CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:partSearchForm ATTR=ID:searchParts

SEARCH SOURCE=REGEXP:"(/part-number/{{!VAR1}}.+?\.html)" EXTRACT="Tracker is $1"
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Answer (score 0):

the macro itself is not well formed.

TAG POS=4 TYPE=DIV ATTR=A:ITEM-NAME* EXTRACT=HREF

You cannot have TYPE=DIV and the ATTR=A

I think it's simply a case where your macro cannot find the element because no such element exists in the DOM